# SpannableString inside a text defined in strings.xml

Tags: android

How would I go about setting a `SpannableString` with a string defined in `strings.xml`?

For example, I have: `%s liked your post`

Then I do

```
SpannableString usernameSS = new SpannableString(username);
usernameSS.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), 0, username.length(), 0);
getString(R.string.like_post, usernameSS);
```

But it doesn't work - the style doesn't get applied, I know I could use HTML's `<b><i>` but is there a way to do this without having to resort to HTML? As I may need to insert a more complex styling later via `TextAppearanceSpan`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep, here the order matter:

```
String finalString = getString(R.string.like_post, username);
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(finalString); 
int startIndex = finalString.indexOf(username);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpannable(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), startIndex, startIndex + username.length(), 0);
```

should do it. Please check for the correct start/end index

Comment: works great! do I call `setSpannable` twice if I have 2 strings that I want to style inside? Thanks!

Comment: ok great, thanks! I have another problem that is the 2 strings might be the same as in `%s commented on a post by %s`, the case where the post author is commenting on his own post, then the `indexOf` would always pick the first one (thus not styling the second). But that's another issue I will figure out. Thanks. Accept is coming on its way

Comment: you can use `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`